# Real time screen streaming from PC to Mobile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, casting, synchronization

I am working on a project in which I am casting the desktop screen to android mobile using jsp page. I am developing android app in unity. We are displaying that jsp page in unity. It is lagging so much. I want to achieve synchronization in casting.

Here is our **C# Code** for android app.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Threading;
public class LoadSprite : MonoBehaviour {
public float sensitivityX = 15F;
public float sensitivityY = 15F;
string url = "http://" + ServerConstant.ipadd + ":" + ServerConstant.portno 
+ "/VRGamming/pages/phone.jsp?methodId=screenshot";

void Start () {

    //InvokeRepeating("UpdateInterval", 0f, 0.066f);
    InvokeRepeating("UpdateInterval", 0f, 0.0762f);
    Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
}

void UpdateInterval()
{

    StartCoroutine(disp());
}

IEnumerator disp()
{

    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    while (!www.isDone)
        yield return null;
    GameObject image = GameObject.Find("RawImage");
    image.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = www.texture;
    DestroyImmediate(www.texture);
    www.Dispose();
    image = null;
    Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
 }


  }
```

Comment: take a look at moonlight( http://moonlight-stream.com/ )  (nvidia streaming to mobile.. that can get you 60fps).

also easymovietexture in asset store if you just want something quick and dirty(you can use something like vlc to make a stream that easymovietexture can show. that too will however be more laggy than the gpu done video encoding on the pc with moonlight)

also you shouldn't let UpdateInterval() start disp() before the previous disp() has finished. this itself alone can cause major hiccups of loading loads of data that you never show.

Answer (score 1):

Your bottleneck is likely that the images are not compressed enough to achieve 'real time' in-sync screen casting.

Sending a direct raw screenshot of a 1920 x 1080 display would be around a mb or 2 as a raw bmp.

Perhaps try something like :
https://github.com/aleh/jpegator

As a pre-processor for the images before sending them across the network.
Perhaps the other solution would be to perhaps use SharpZipLib - and rar/zip the byte data yourself to as small a size as possible, and then unzip the data on the client/receivers end.

Unfortunately, it is unlikely you will be able to get 100% in sync casting.

You will either get a delay from the image bandwidth (size)
or a delay from the processing time required to compress and decompress the image (processing).